# Deligne-Mumford space defined in complex geometry category

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry

Is Deligne-Mumford space could also be defined in the complex geometry context? I check wiki, it says we can similarly define Riemann surface with nodes and stability condition, I am wondering if there is any reference providing more details about this aspect. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to know if the "analytification" of the DM-stacks of stable marked curves (equipped with their "universal" structure) enjoy an analogous universal property in the complex-analytic category? This is not a tautology, so you probably won't see it in the work of Bers (whom I assume doesn't work with non-smooth bases, for instance), but it can be deduced by analytic analogues of certain algebraic constructions (ultimately deriving from universality of analytified Hilbert schemes, which also requires a proof).  Please clarify your question. 

Comment: Hi,Bcnrd,thanks! So $\bar{M_{g,n}}$ can be defined in complex geometry,it is the space of smooth or nodal Riemann surface with genus $g$ and $n$ marked points and satisfying stability condition, is there any reference showing that it is compact and hausdorff? I didn't see any referece, but it should be basic material!

Comment: All "basic", but no ref. with proofs (e.g., not the nice Encyclopedia of Math book on complex spaces). Hand-waving not enough? :) To rigorously prove analytification of alg. moduli space is analytic mod. space, key ingredients (beyond GAGA) are: analytic Proj and analytic relative ampleness. I wrote "Rel. ampleness in rigid-analytic geometry" (includes analytic Proj) so works in the complex-analytic case; sec. 4 handles Hilbert & Quot functors, and methods adapt to $\overline{M}_{g,n}$ using rel. ample line bundles. Chow's Lemma for DM-stacks + alg. properness yields compact & Hausdorff. QED

Comment: One addendum to my previous comment: I've never read anything by Bers (apart from the nifty mnemonic to remember the quotient rule for derivatives in his calculus book), so I have no idea how his stuff interacts with the method I outline above. It is not necessary to know anything about Bers' work to develop the theory (which isn't to say that there's anything wrong with looking at his stuff for inspriration; I simply never did so). 

Comment: Bers's stuff is quite different from the algebro-geometric approach.  It is more in line with the classical approach to the moduli space of Riemann surfaces that Bers and Ahlfors developed in the early '50's, following ideas of Teichmuller (using tools like hyperbolic geometry and quasiconformal maps).  While this approach isn't the best approach for studying algebro-geometric problems, it has been very influential among other "users" of the moduli space of curves (eg in Kleinian groups, complex dynamics, hyperbolic geometry, ...).

Comment: Andy, perhaps you can answer some questions I've wondered for a long time: from the pre-Grothedieck viewpoint of Bers and Alfhors, was the moduli space (or Teichmuller space) just "a construction" (in which case I wonder their reason to study it beyond "seems a good thing to do") or was it characterized by an abstract property that endowed it with intrinsic significance relative to general "families" (expressed in some concrete terms)? And from their point of view was it possible to study the space *without* knowing how it was constructed (as is often done with Grothendieck's approach)? 

Comment: Hi,BCnrd, in symplectic GW theory, we have a Gromov compactness on the space of stable maps, if we allow the target symplectic manifold be a point, then can we say we can the answer,that is, the space of smooth or nodal Riemann surface with genus $g$ and $n$ marked points and satisfying stability condition is a compact orbifold? but it seems that Gromov compactness is for Gromov Topology, it doesn't fit into the concept of moduli space!

Comment: Dear HYYY: I don't know symplectic geometry, so I suppose your comment is indicating a context for which the approach of Bers and Alfhors is more appropriate.  But are you also asking again the question about the compactness? I briefly sketched in my 2nd comment about why the analytic moduli space is compact and Hausdorff (in the orbifold sense). There is no adequate literature reference (as far as I know); sorry. Hopefully you can get something useful out of my sketch.  I had to figure out all of this stuff for myself, and assumed everyone else has to do the same. 

Comment: @BCnrd : I'm not a historian, so don't take the following too seriously.  Ahlfors and Bers didn't really consider M_g to be a space w/ a universal property.  AFAIK, they had 2 motivations.  One, they wanted to make rigorous Riemann's parameter count for M_g.  Two, they were interested in understanding Fuchsian and Kleinian groups.  The latter might explain why they studied Teichmuller space more than M_g, as Teichmuller space really is just a space of representations.  I actually think they found it pretty surprising when they discovered that Teichmuller space had a complex structure...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure where to point you for full details of this, but quite a few details are in some old research announcements of Bers.  See his papers

MR0361051 (50 #13497) 
Bers, Lipman
Spaces of degenerating Riemann surfaces. Discontinuous groups and Riemann surfaces (Proc. Conf., Univ. Maryland, College Park, Md., 1973), pp. 43--55. Ann. of Math. Studies, No. 79, Princeton Univ. Press, Princeton, N.J., 1974.

and

MR0361165 (50 #13611) 
Bers, Lipman
On spaces of Riemann surfaces with nodes. 
Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 80 (1974), 1219--1222.

and

MR0374496 (51 #10696) 
Bers, Lipman
Deformations and moduli of Riemann surfaces with nodes and signatures. 
Collection of articles dedicated to Werner Fenchel on his 70th birthday. 
Math. Scand. 36 (1975), 12--16.

---

EDIT : Sorry to resurrect this ancient thread, but I heard a lovely talk from Sarah Koch a few weeks ago in which she described a recent paper that she wrote with John Hubbard in which they give a complex-analytic construction of the DM compactification of the moduli space of curves and prove that (as a complex analytic space) it is isomorphic to the analyticification of the usual one.  In particular, this gives all the missing details in Bers's papers above (along with much more).  See their paper "An analytic construction of the Deligne-Mumford compactification of the moduli space of curves" available from Sarah's webpage [here](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~kochs/papers.html).

Answer (score 6):

Another construction of the Deligne-Mumford compactification in the complex-analytic category was carried some years ago by Robbin and Salamon; "A construction of the Deligne-Mumford orbifold", JEMS 8 (2006), 611-699 or http://www.math.ethz.ch/~salamon/PREPRINTS/dmETH.pdf
It contains full details, but their approach is completely different from Bers's one. Robbin and Salamon use techniques from geometric analysis. If you are not afraid of such analysis, take a look.